# Create a list of java methods that ultimately call a specified method

Tags: java, static-code-analysis

I've been tasked to find all of the methods in a large Java application which ultimately call a specific method that needs to be refactored.

To clarify, if the target method is "fixme", and "fixme" is called by "a", "b", and "c", but "a" is called by "d" and "e"; "b" is called by "d", "f", "g", "h", "i"; and "c" is called by "j" and "k". Then "d" is called by ..., etc.
So we have

```
k calls c calls fixme
g calls b calls fixme
```

and so on.

The depth of these call "chains" can get pretty deep and there several dozen that directly call "fixme", so a manual solution will take a while. And this is not going to be the only refactoring task.

So - I'm looking for a tool, or strategy, that can do this work while I lazily watch.

I am aware of of IDEs such as Eclipse that lets you find references to methods, but those work one method at a time. Executing the code with trace messages requires full code coverage which is not feasible (nor reliable as I could miss one). I'm really looking for some kind of static code analyzer with this kind of feature.

Comment: Your question is off-topic on SO. Try it on on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Make sure to get acquainted with their guidelines first.

Comment: Most IDE's can do this. You're probably just using the wrong tool. In Netbeans, `Find Usages` will get you all references to the code entity. `Call Hierarchy` will get you the tree structure you're looking for. I don't know what the equivalent is for Eclipse, but I'd bet that it has both available. Whichever one you're using, try the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse can do that. In the eclipse call view (CTRL+ALT+H when the cursor is on the method) you can expand each node, to see the full call stack.

When all is expanded, right click on the top node and select "Copy expanded hierarchy".

Only problem with this solution is that I could not find a way to auto-expand it, so you have to click once for each call.